# Equivalent of LocalBroadcastManager without Android support library

Tags: android, sdk, android-broadcast

There are lots of examples on StackOverflow and elsewhere that use the class `LocalBroadcastManager` to avoid broadcasting events outside of an app.

However, this class uses the Android support library as shown in the package name: `android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager`.

Is there an equivalent of `LocalBroadcastManager` in the standard SDK that does not use the Android support library?

It does not seem that the `sendBroadcast` method in `android.content.Context` has this kind of security granularity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it doesn't exist, If you want to recreate this class you can read the source code to implement yourself without using the support lib.
Anyway, what's the problem using the support lib? it's lightweight.

A bit workaround could be using the normal BroadCastReceiver and put [`<android:exported="false">`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#Security) on your manifest, inside this receiver, this avoid to other apps send you intents, so you are faking a local receiver.

Note: I said faking, because the LocalBroadcastManager has optimizations, by not spread the intent to the system...

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually I came to the same conclusion after having read the source code of LocalBroadcastManager and after better having understood the rationnal behind the Android support libraries. Anyway today I would use something like EventBus.